# Multiply certain columns of a 2D tensor by a scaler

Tags: tensorflow

Is their a way using tf functions to multiply certain columns of a 2D tensor by a scaler?

e.g. multiply the second and third column of a matrix by 2:

[[2,3,4,5],[4,3,4,3]] -> [[2,6,8,5],[4,6,8,3]]

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Thank you Psidom for the reply. Unfortunately I am not using a tf.Variable, so it seems I have to use tf.slice.

What I am trying to do is to multiply all components by 2 of a single-sided PSD, except for the DC component and the Nyquist frequency component, to conserve the total power when going from a double-sided spectrum to a single-sided spectrum.

This would correspond to: 2*PSD[:,1:-1] if it was a numpy array.

Here is my attempt with tf.assign and tf.slice:

x['PSD'] = tf.assign(tf.slice(x['PSD'], [0, 1], [tf.shape(x['PSD'])[0], tf.shape(x['PSD'])[1] - 2]),
    tf.scalar_mul(2, tf.slice(x['PSD'], [0, 1], [tf.shape(x['PSD'])[0], tf.shape(x['PSD'])[1] - 2]))) # single-sided power spectral density.

However:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tensor is a variable, you can do this by slicing the columns you want to update and then use `tf.assign`:

```py
x = tf.Variable([[2,3,4,5],[4,3,4,3]])
x = tf.assign(x[:,1:3], x[:,1:3]*2)        # update the second and third columns and assign 
                                           # the new tensor to x   ​
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(x))
#[[2 6 8 5]
# [4 6 8 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up taking 3 different slices and concatenating them together, with the middle slice multiplied by 2. Probably not the most efficient way, but it works:

x['PSD'] = tf.concat([tf.slice(x['PSD'], [0, 0], [tf.shape(x['PSD'])[0], 1]),
    tf.scalar_mul(2, tf.slice(x['PSD'], [0, 1], [tf.shape(x['PSD'])[0], tf.shape(x['PSD'])[1] - 2])), 
    tf.slice(x['PSD'], [0, tf.shape(x['PSD'])[1] - 1], [tf.shape(x['PSD'])[0], 1])], 1) # single-sided power spectral density.